# Detect if event listener is attached to directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my directive, I have the following event defined:

```
function wizard() {
    return {
        scope: {
            raiseCancel: '&onCancel'
        },
```

And then further down, I attempt to check if a listener is attached. If one is not, I want to execute some default behavior.

```
if (scope.raiseCancel) scope.raiseCancel();
else $window.history.back();
```

But apparently `scope.raiseCancel` will always be truthy because Angular assigns an anonymous function that calls `angular.noop` when no event listener is attached. How can I detect if there is a listener for my event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle your raiseCancel as an event handler, returning false to prevent the default behaviour.

Of course that mean code change in the raiseCancel handler(s) passed

```
if (scope.raiseCancel == null || scope.raiseCancel() !== false) {
    $window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: But I want the default behavior to happen if there is no event handler. This would require an event handler to be present and to return false.

Comment: Nope,  if it returns nothing then it's executed.  You need to return false not to execute the default behavior

Comment: Edited the snippet,  but what you tell the first part of the condition is probably useless